# How to invert a circuit

Tags: sensor, switches

I have a door sensor that works when the door open. I need to use it for other purpose so when the door open the circuit turned off.. While the door closed the circuit should goes on.

I want to link it to a on-lamp that should turned off when the door is open..

Comment: How does the sensor work? Maybe it has terminals that are normally open and terminals that are normally closed and you would need only to reconnect one or two wires

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the switch you used it might have 3 terminals, two of these might close when the other terminals close.

If not maybe you can replace the switch with a 3 terminal one.

If that is also not possible a solution would be an electronic switch for the lamp with a TRIAC or a relay.